# Can "in real" be used instead of "in reality" in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Can

***'A tomato is a fruit in reality, not a vegetable'***

be also written as

***'A tomato is a fruit in real, not a vegetable'***

?

Comment: In a word, no, you can't.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you.

Comment: I would request anyone who downvoted the question to please point out the flaw so that I can correct things in the future.

Comment: See the closure votes. You are supposed to show what attempts you have made to find out the answer for yourself, e.g. searching online for the two phrases.

Comment: Check the meanings of *for real* and *in reality*.  They are similar and should demonstrate the usage and difference between the two words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

“Real” is an adjective. “In” is a preposition. A preposition (except those that form part of an intransitive verb) must be followed by a noun (or a pronoun). Such a noun may be modified by an adjective, but the noun must be present.

Comment: Thank You so much for providing the technicalities :)